# JSDoc: Is conditional ignore possible?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there a way to ignore some documented symbols conditionally?
I'd like to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
/**
* @ignore if dev
*/
var a = 42;

/**
* @ignore if prod
*/
var b = 24;
```

In this example I would like to have my JSDoc generator to only document `var a` if I configured my generator to `dev` and vice versa for `var b`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you reach a conclusion for this question?

Comment: No, sadly i didnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own [jsdoc plugin](http://usejsdoc.org/about-plugins.html) to test an ignore condition and set its value in `doclet.ignore` property. Setting it to `true` will prevent the doclet being processed - not adding it to the final documentation.

```
exports.defineTags = function(dictionary) {

    var env = require('jsdoc/env');

    /*
     * Usage: @customIgnore prod, test
     */
    dictionary.defineTag('customIgnore', {

        mustHaveValue: true,

        onTagged: function(doclet, tag) {
            var i;

            // "envParams" is a property of your jsdoc.json
            var environments = env.conf.envParams; 

           // Will hold "prod, test"
            var tagValue = tag.value;

            var conditionValues = tag.value.split(",");
            for (i = 0; i < conditionValues.length && !doclet.ignore; i++) {            
                if (environments.indexOf(conditionValues[i].trim()) !== -1) {
                    doclet.ignore = true;
                }
            }

        }
    });
};
```